# Integration of CkFinder with Ckeditor failed in my Asp.net mvc3.How can i successfully integrate it?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, ckeditor

my ckeditor works great except the browse server and other functionalities.

**In config file of ckeditor**

```
    CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function (config) {
    config.htmlEncodeOutput = true,
    config.filebrowserBrowseUrl = true,
    config.filebrowserImageBrowseUrl=true
   };

    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace("profiel_lange_beschrijving", { toolbar: 'Full' });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor(editor, '~/Scripts/ckfinder');
    CKEDITOR.replace('editor',
    {
    filebrowserBrowseUrl: '~/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
    filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '~/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',

   filebrowserUploadUrl: '~/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx? command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
    filebrowserImageUploadUrl: '~/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?   command=QuickUpload&type=Images'
  command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
});
```

How can i successfully integrate ckfinder in ckeditor?  please help friends

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Integrate Ckfinder in ckeditor .then add this in your Razor view

```
CKEDITOR.replace('editor',
{
 filebrowserImageBrowseUrl: '/Scripts/ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=UploadedImages',
 filebrowserUploadUrl: '/Scripts/ckfinder/core/connector/aspx/connector.aspx?       command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
 filebrowserImageUploadUrl:'/UploadImage/Upload'

}
);
```

where 'editor' is the textbox id .

then create an UploadImage controller

```
  public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase upload, string CKEditorFuncNum, string CKEditor, string langCode)
    {
        string url; // url to return
        string message; // message to display (optional)
        message = "Image successfully saved ";

   //do save image code here
        url =  "/" + path + "/" + filename;
      string output = @"<html><body><script>window.parent.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(" + CKEditorFuncNum + ", \"" + url + "\", \"" + message + "\");</script></body></html>";

            return Content(output);
        }
```

Try this it works great

Answer (score 1):

You might be over-complicating things. Here's a link to the CKFinder [installation guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Installation), and a link to the [configuration guide](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Configuration), both are for the [ASP.NET](http://download.cksource.com/CKFinder/CKFinder%20for%20ASP.NET/2.2.1/ckfinder_aspnet_2.2.1.zip) version of CKFinder.

Comment: hi there is no proper documentation for integrating ckfinder to ckeditor

Comment: it shiowing parser error.how can i integrate it in  razor view?/

Comment: Here's the integration guide [link](http://docs.cksource.com/CKFinder_2.x/Developers_Guide/ASP.NET/Integration). As for the parser problem, try posting the question in our forum [link](http://cksource.com/forums/).

Comment: Some one already posted this issue in the forum.iam waiting for the replay.still showing issues on integrating ckfuinder with ckeditor.no proper documentation available

Comment: hi upload image works perfectly but Browser not working any one please help me